# WCF Service hosted in Worker Role on Windows Azure that acts like a proxy and needs to call other services hosted in other Worker Roles

Tags: wcf, azure, azure-worker-roles

as you can see, I am relatively new on SO  please don't kill me after posting this question :) I will do my best to describe the dilemma I am currently in.

I am creating something like a "Guardian Service" that is hosted on Windows Azure inside a Worker Role. This service has external ports, that can be accessed via HTTPS to allow clients to call it's service methods.

The WCF service is meant to call other services hosted in other Worker Roles that have only internal ports open, and which can be accessed only through the use of the Guardian Service. That's the main idea. Similar to a proxy or something.

I read already an excellent article from Jim O'Neil, what the caveats are when you try to access internal service points from within other WCF Services hosted in worker Roles:

His blog [Troubleshooting Endpoints on a WCF Web Role](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2011/07/11/troubleshooting-endpoints-on-a-wcf-web-role.aspx)

This is not the point for this question, and totally clear to me how to do that.

I have no idea at the moment, how I could do this, without implementing every contract from every single service I want to make accessible from within the Guardian Service to the outside world.

There must be a better way to decouple those things.

Any tips are appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know the exact requirements for your project but I would say that what you are looking for is WCF Routing. I've used it in the past to redirect requests for different versions of Workflow instances.

The way it works is completely transparent to the client connecting to its endpoint. The router implementation must decide where to send the requests to, based on the request data (message headers and body).

In your case, if you are using SOAP and namespaces correctly, you might be able to base your decision on the message soap address and then send the request to the correct endpoint. You could also look at the Action property of the message.

Some links that might be useful: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517423.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/227699/RoutingService-on-Azure

Comment: Hey Tiago, the codeplex article is really amazing and full of great concepts. Perfect! Thank you :) I think a router fits quite perfectly into my scenario.